# Disable first column for row move up/down in table using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I got stuck, don't know what I have missed.

I am able to  move up/down a row in a table, but what I need is, first column cell value should remain same. Below is my code.

My HTML file:

```
<div ng-show="showStoppageTable" align="center" class="form-group-sm">
    <table id="stoppageTable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-xs ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="btn-info">serialNo</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Stoppage Name</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Description</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Route order</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="stoppage in StoppageData">
                <td>{{ stoppage.orderId }}</td>
                <td>{{ stoppage.stoppageName }}</td>
                <td>{{ stoppage.description }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="floating-buttons" align="center">
                        <button type="button" name="moveUpButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveUpModal" ng-click="r.ForMoveUp($index)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="MoveUP"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" name="moveDownButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveDownModal" ng-click="r.ForMoveDown($index)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="MoveDown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="floating-buttons" align="center">
                        <button type="button" name="deleteStoppage" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteStoppage" ng-click="r.deleteStoppage(stoppage,$index)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="DeleteStoppage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>                                      
                    </div> 
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
```

My `ctrl.js` file:

```
vm.ForMoveUp = function (rowIndex) {
    var StoppageData = $scope.StoppageData;
    if (rowIndex > 0) {
        var temp = StoppageData[rowIndex - 1];
        StoppageData[rowIndex - 1] = StoppageData[rowIndex];
        StoppageData[rowIndex] = temp;
        $scope.rowIndex--;
    }
}

vm.ForMoveDown = function (rowIndex) {
    var StoppageData = $scope.StoppageData;
    if (rowIndex < StoppageData.length - 1) {
        var temp = StoppageData[rowIndex + 1];
        StoppageData[rowIndex + 1] = StoppageData[rowIndex];
        StoppageData[rowIndex] = temp;   }      
}
```

Comment: any plunk / jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:
On click of Up/Down, the `stoppageName` and `description` should move but the `orderId` should remain intact.

```
    vm.ForMoveUp = function(rowIndex) {
       var StoppageData = $scope.StoppageData;
       if (rowIndex > 0) {
           var temp = StoppageData[rowIndex - 1];
           StoppageData[rowIndex - 1].stoppageName = StoppageData[rowIndex].stoppageName;
           StoppageData[rowIndex - 1].description = StoppageData[rowIndex].description;
           StoppageData[rowIndex].stoppageName = temp.stoppageName;
           StoppageData[rowIndex].description = temp.description;
           $scope.rowIndex--;
       }
   }

   vm.ForMoveDown = function(rowIndex) {
       var StoppageData = $scope.StoppageData;
       if (rowIndex < StoppageData.length - 1) {
           var temp = StoppageData[rowIndex + 1];
           StoppageData[rowIndex + 1].stoppageName = StoppageData[rowIndex].stoppageName;
           StoppageData[rowIndex + 1].description = StoppageData[rowIndex].description;
           StoppageData[rowIndex].stoppageName = temp.stoppageName;
           StoppageData[rowIndex].description = temp.description;
       }
   }
```

Let me know if this works for you, or you have some other requirement

Comment: also is possible to be dynamic, instead of statically assigning particular properties / value.. thanks for reply.

Comment: it didn't work ? or this not what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is the way i am looking for. Thanks i have modified little as below worked for me. vm.ForMoveUp = function (rowIndex) {
            var StoppageData = $scope.StoppageData;
            if (rowIndex > 0) {
                var temp = StoppageData[rowIndex - 1];
                StoppageData[rowIndex - 1] = StoppageData[rowIndex];
                StoppageData[rowIndex - 1].orderId = StoppageData[rowIndex].orderId - 1;
                StoppageData[rowIndex] = temp;
                StoppageData[rowIndex].orderId = temp.orderId+1;
                $scope.rowIndex--; }   }